# Javascript find class

Tags: javascript, html, validation, class

I am trying to create some javascript for my custom form, without using of jquery. So I have a couple of inputs. What I want is to find to do this with javascript.

```
if ($(".text-field").hasClass("input-validation-error")) {
   $(".error").css("display", " block");
      }
   else if ($(".text-field").hasClass("valid")) {
      $(".error").css("display", " none");
   }
   else {
      $(".error").css("display", " none");
   }
}
```

But I need the thing, that means it applies it to that specific input (this) statement is it possible, here is an example of my html

```
<div class="field-holder">
     <input id="name" name="name"/>
     <label for="name" class="error" style="display:none;">This field is required.</label>
</div>
```

The class input validation error is applied automatically.

Comment: Using something like `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");` will give you the DOM element which has the class 'example'. So then you can just use that to assign certain CSS to that class. But if you do not have a good reason to not use jQuery then you should use jQuery.

Comment: [Show the code that you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and ask a specific answerable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you want the non jQuery solutiuon, but that code is totally wrong to start.

`$(".text-field").hasClass("input-validation-error")` only looks at the FIRST element, it does not look at every element.

Use

```
if ( $(".text-field.input-validation-error").length ) {

}
```

But the problem is the fact that you have multiple error fields and the code does not know magically what elements that they should be shown. Your code will show/hide all of them, not just the ones that have the issue.

Why use JavaScript at all?  You can use CSS instead of JavaScript to have the error messages shown. Simple CSS selectors can do the work.

```
.text-field + label.error {
    display: none;
}

.text-field.input-validation-error + label.error {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go all the functions in pure javascript. The source is jQuery.js and my own tests.

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
    if (element.classList) {
        return element.classList.contains(className);
    } else {
        return new RegExp('(^| )' + className + '( |$)', 'gi').test(element.className);
    }
}

function addClass(element, className) {
    if (!hasClass(element, className)) {
        if (element.classList) {
          element.classList.add(className);
        }
        else {
          element.className += ' ' + className;
        }
    }
}

function removeClass(element, className) {
    if (element.classList) {
        return element.classList.remove(className);
    } else {
        return element.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
    }
}


function toggleClass(element, className) {
    if (hasClass(element, className)) {
        removeClass(element, className);
    } else {
        addClass(element, className);
    }
}
```